# How open native call details screen for a particular call log in Samsung and HTC android device using intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an android application to show all call logs in the list and when user taps on any call log, i need to open native app's call details screen for that tapped call log.

I have tried following code snippet and it works fine in **Emulator** (Pure android OS.)

```
Intent mDetailsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); mDetailsIntent.setType(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);

Uri mUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(mCallLog.getId()));

mDetailsIntent.setData(mUri);

startActivity(mDetailsIntent);
```

But when I run it on **Samsung** device, it shown the last recent call log's details screen each time regardless of call log id.

And for **HTC** devices, it throws **ActivityNotFoundException**.

Following log cat is for HTC device.

```
**03-10 14:19:00.772: D/LogsFragment(20947): Call log details uri==>content://call_log/calls/62

03-10 14:19:00.782: W/System.err(20947): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://call_log/calls/62 }

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1638)

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1510)

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3258)

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:833)

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:856)

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at com.cwiker.fragments.LogsFragment.onItemClick(LogsFragment.java:219)

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1099)

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:4758)

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2556)

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3223)

03-10 14:19:00.792: W/System.err(20947):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)

03-10 14:19:00.802: W/System.err(20947):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

03-10 14:19:00.802: W/System.err(20947):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)

03-10 14:19:00.802: W/System.err(20947):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)

03-10 14:19:00.802: W/System.err(20947):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-10 14:19:00.802: W/System.err(20947):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

03-10 14:19:00.802: W/System.err(20947):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

03-10 14:19:00.802: W/System.err(20947):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

03-10 14:19:00.802: W/System.err(20947):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)**
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: can you send the log cat please!!

Comment: Hi Jitesh, I've added logcat plese check.